# WCF internet explorer (starter)

Tags: wcf, internet-explorer

i created a  simple WCF library and hosting the service in a console application with BasicHttpBinding endpoint .

While the console host is running . I tried to open the service in IE9 /Firefox .....
http://localhost:8080/EService/basic .    In IE9 it shows error, and in Firefox it doesn't show anything.

I'm running VS 2010 as Admin

Im attaching the code
https://rapidshare.com/files/3306100109/ChatSolution.rar

Comment: What is the error, your link didn't work for me ;) . Can you also post your config?

Comment: What error does it show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have your service endpoint defined at 2 places in your EvalServiceLibarary and your ConsoleChat app.

Remove the ServiceModel Section from the service library and just have it in your ConsoleChat Application. I did try the below config in your console app and it works:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Metadata">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />          
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NoSecurityPlusRM">
          <reliableSession enabled="true" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Metadata" name="EvalServiceLibrary.EvalService">
        <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="EvalServiceLibrary.IEvalService" />
        <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="NoSecurityPlusRM" contract="EvalServiceLibrary.IEvalService" />        
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/evals"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Now just browse to http://localhost:8080/evals from your browser and you can see the service page.